# Research interest for PhD application

Tags: phd

I am applying for PhD programs in the USA, one of the schools requested a PhD research interest. The problem is I do not know how to write it. Also, they have requested a copy of masters thesis abstract, But in my masters I did not done a thesis.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. On this occasion, we will merge the two posts since we don't want to lose the answers.